# Add spacer in Eclipse Toolbar

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I would like to add a flush-left (ragged-right) item in a **toolbar** of my Eclipse E4 application.

Toolbar items in Eclipse are ragged-left by default, so this is what I would like to achieve:

```
      toolbar
+------------------------------------------------+
| I1 |                      | I2 | I3 | ... | IN |
+------------------------------------------------+
      <-------------------->
              spacer?
```

Item `I1` would be flush-left thanks to the effect of the spacer control in between `I1` and `I2` (if I got the meaning of a spacer in the first place).

---

[I know](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=469015&goto=1032781&#msg_1032781) that a **stretch**-tagged `ToolControl` in between items of a *trimbar* will work as a spacer; but that does not work on *toolbars*.

I also tried to add toolbar elements as extension points in the *plugin.xml* following the instructions I read from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969715/eclipse-rcp-right-aligned-search-field-in-toolbar/6241152?noredirect=1#comment99881017_6241152). I am not sure whether this is simply not E4-compatible or if I made some mistake.

Ideas?

---

<sub>Likely a duplicate of [How do I add a spacer to an Eclipse RCP toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246597/how-do-i-add-a-spacer-to-an-eclipse-rcp-toolbar)</sub>

Comment: Extension point menu stuff is Eclipse 3.x compatibility mode only and will be completely ignored by a pure e4 RCP.

Comment: I see, thanks. But was it possible then back in 3.x ?

Comment: Current 3.x compatibilty mode is just e4 with a lot of extra code, I don't think any of that extra code does this. I don't remember if the original 3.x code had anything else, I doubt it. It might be possible to do this by modifying the tool bar renderer - but that is very hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `ToolControl` to the `Toolbar` and use a class like this for the control:

```java
public class SpacerControl
{
  public SpacerControl()
  {
    super();
  }


  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct(final Composite parent)
  {
    new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE)
      .setLayout(new FillLayout());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Greg, that actually makes a lot of sense. I tried your solution however the `ToolControl` I placed *before* the spacer `ToolControl` is still right-aligned, sticked to all other items.

Comment: (Persisted state is cleared and the spacer object is actually created)

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. This code just adds a space between tool items, nothing else.

Comment: I don't think stretching like that inside a Toolbar is possible. It is the Trimbar renderer that does the stretching and it doesn't look inside the toolbars.

Comment: Ok, got it. For one moment I thought that a `FillLayout` component would grab the available space. Anyway, as an ugly workaround, I believe I will probably stick to a GridLayout (child of) composite with minimum size in its layout data.